# How to get value from LWC Lighting Datatable cell and act upon it

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to do something that seems like it should be simple,but I obviously do not understand something.

We have a custom document object, it relates to another custom object. I have a datatable listing the documents on the record page of the custom object it relates to.

The last column has a download icon, I don't want to display any data there just the icon (the 'xxx' in the JS is just testing so there is a value there).

When I say download that is going to be done from a remote service and I have code that will do it, I just need to get the value from this row and pass it to the download code. For whatever reason I can get the data to the onclick function.

I have tried using target. a wide variety of fields, and event. a wide variety of fields. Everything comes back 'undefined' except if I put event.detail (with nothing further) then it always evaluates as the value '1', no matter which row I am clicking on.

I obviously don't understand the most basic parts of passing a value from the table back to the controller, would anyone care to help out?

**HTML:**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="File List">

    <lightning-datatable data={documents} columns={columns} key-field="Id" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-datatable>
</lightning-card>
```

**Javascript:**

```
export default class TestLWC extends LightningElement {
@track columns = [
    {
        label: 'File Name',
        fieldName: 'nameUrl',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' },
        target: '_blank'},
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'File Type',
        fieldName: 'File_Type__c',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Related To',
        fieldName: 'relatedTo',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Related_To__c' },
        target: '_blank'},
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        fieldName: 'test',
        label: 'Download',
        cellAttributes: { iconName: 'action:download', onClick: 'handleDownloadClick' }
    }

];
@api recordId;
@track error;
@track documents = [];

handleClick(event) {
    const displayStr = event.detail;
    //I have also tried target here
    alert('hello '+displayStr);

}
//@wire(getAllDocs)
@wire(getRelatedDocs,{recordId: '$recordId'})
wiredDocs(result) {
    const { data, error } = result;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('SCH data '+result);
    if(data) {
        let nameUrl;
        let relatedTo;
        let test;
        this.documents = data.map(row => {
            nameUrl = `${row.File_Link__c}`;
            relatedTo = `/${row.Related_To__c}`;
            test='xxx';
            return {...row ,nameUrl,relatedTo,test}
        })
        this.error = null;
    }
    if(error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.opportunities = [];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the actions type with a button icon and without the drop down menu.
For this, you need to add `onrowaction` attribute to the lightning-datatable.

Then once you click on the button icon, the function `handleRowAction` will be invoked based on the action name and `event.detail.row` captures which row triggered the button click event.

The sample code below is a tweaked version of the example from the LWC guide : [Data table with row actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example)

[Playground version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/D0VqSLGK/14/edit)

**withRowActions.html**

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-m-around--medium" style="width: 30rem;">
        <article class="slds-tile">
            <h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title="Record details"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Record details</a></h3>
            <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Name">Name:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate">{record.name}</dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Balance">Balance:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate">
                        <lightning-formatted-number value={record.amount} format-style="currency"></lightning-formatted-number>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</template>
```

**withRowActions.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import fetchDataHelper from './fetchDataHelper';

const actions = [
    { label: 'Download', name: 'download' }
];

const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name' },
    { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'Close At', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date' },
    {type: 'button-icon', typeAttributes: {  
        iconName: 'utility:download',
        label: 'Download',  
        name: 'download',  
        variant: 'bare',
        alternativeText: 'download',        
        disabled: false
    }}
];

export default class DatatableWithRowActions extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = columns;
    @track record = {};

    async connectedCallback() {
        this.data = await fetchDataHelper({ amountOfRecords: 100 });
    }

    handleRowAction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const row = event.detail.row;
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'download':
                this.showRowDetails(row);
                break;                      
            default:
        }
    }

    showRowDetails(row) {
        this.record = row;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row.name));
    }

}
```

**fetchDataHelper.js** (used only display sample data in the table)

```
const recordMetadata = {
    name: 'name',
    email: 'email',
    website: 'url',
    amount: 'currency',
    phone: 'phoneNumber',
    closeAt: 'dateInFuture',
};

export default function fetchDataHelper({ amountOfRecords }) {
    return fetch('https://data-faker.herokuapp.com/collection', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            amountOfRecords,
            recordMetadata,
        }),
    }).then(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Chosen as answer. Thank you so much Shamina for such a complete and detailed explanation!

Comment: @ScottH7a9 Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing you use the "actions" type for your cell and provide it with the button and it's features. The drawback is that it is inside a dropdown and not just a button in the cell.

If you are 100% set on having a custom button in the cell that does what you need you can specify custom types for datatables that will allow you to achieve your requirement. Have a look at the following documentation: [Lightning Datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)

Scroll down to the section labelled **"Creating Custom Data Types"**, this is how I managed to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a pretty simple component, I would be willing to change it slightly, I'm not sure if I want the level of effort to create a custom data type. I think I will go with the button idea. Do you know where I could find an example of how it works? The issue I am having is how to get the value of the id for the row when the button is clicked?

Comment: The answer and example provided by @Shamina is definitely a winner!